# Grunt subtasks run in parallel

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, gruntjs

According to [this](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#custom-tasks), tasks can be asynchronous.
In my case, I have some tasks that each one has several subtasks (or targets) that run in order.

For example:

```
copy: {
    foo: {
      // concat task "foo" target options and files go here.
    },
    bar: {
      // concat task "bar" target options and files go here.
    }
  }
```

but the `copy:foo` takes too long so I would like the subtasks of copy run in parallel. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Use

```
setTimeout(your_func1, 0);
setTimeout(your_func2, 0)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please? What is `your_func1`?

Comment: It is function name without brackets, like copy.foo or copy.bar